# Small space between footer and bottom of page

Tags: html, css

```css
body, html {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Images/firepit2.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:visited {
  
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:active {
  
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#Navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding: 10px;
}

#Navigation li {
  display: inline; 
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#Greeting {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#Wrapper p {
  line-height: 1.1em; 
  margin-top: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-style: italic;
}

footer p {
  float: left; 
}

footer ul {
  float: right; 
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
}

footer::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

#Copyright {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact {
  margin-right: 25px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Contact li {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Woodrow Lawn and Turf</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<!-- DEVELOPER NOTES -->
  <!--

    - Keywords and description meta are still subject to change by the client.
    - Make sure to add correct target attributes and file paths to the nav links.
    - All images used in this mockup are subject to copyright currently.
    - Make sure to add alternate font families to the font-family style. (2 only)
    - Fix non-colored area below the footer.

  -->
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="Logo">Woodrow Lawn and Turf</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul id="Navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Lawn Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Dirt Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Flower Bed Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Patio Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Firepit Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Commercial and Business Stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <h1 id="Greeting">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Footer">
    <footer>
      <p id="Copyright">&copy; Copyright Woodrow Lawn and Turf LLC 2017</p>
      <ul id="Contact">
        <li>Contact:</li>
        <li><a href="tel:+1-999-999-9999">(999)999-9999</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:stuffcompany@comp.net">stuffcompany@comp.net</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
  

 

 
</body>
  
  
  









</html>
```

This question has probably been asked a million times, but I've tried a good bit of common solutions to it and still no result. There is a small space between the footer and end of the page, showing the background and I don't know what is causing it. **UPDATE:** I don't know what happened, but it seems that the space has disappeared or something. Really weird ghost browsers I guess.

Comment: ts fine here, using FF in win10

Comment: not seeing the space either.. what browser? Post screenshot of your experience.

Comment: i dont see any space between ur footer and buttom page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to have understood the problem. There is a margin applied to the footer tag that leaks out from div#Footer. It is because of the collapsing margins in CSS. If you give a 1px pixel padding or a transparent 1px border to the div, the footer tag margin will be contained.

If you don't need the margin you could simply remove it:

```
#Footer > div {
margin-top: 0;
}
```